# Updating the data in same graph instead of opening in multiple window?

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to do what working code (please see below) does. Working code reads each id given in the class parament and update the result ( True/False) in same same window while counting number of trues and false. Issue with this code it I need have the list of ids defined before processing. How can I avoid giving the list of ids in the class parameter? Assuming we get id one at a time, I would like to update the same window. For loop in my "non-working code" is trying to replicate the arrival of one id at a time while updating the data in the UI. However, it opens up multiple window  instead of updating the data in same window.

Working code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor,QPixmap
# from neo4jj import neo4j
import time

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, id_list=[1,12,13,14,15,15,123,12,11,113,115,211,311,51,31,21,131,111], parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # counter
        self.correct = 0
        self.incorrect = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 8pt Arial}")
        self.qLbl = QLabel("Not yet initialized")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)
        self.id_list = id_list
        self.mPixmap = QPixmap()
        self.qTimer = QTimer()
        self.qTimer.setInterval(1000)
        self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.getSensorValue)
        self.qTimer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.qTimer.start()

        self.color = QColor()
        # self.update()

    def getSensorValue(self):
        for ids_ in self.id_list:
            time.sleep(1)
        # Reads Neo4j database to match with paper

            result = (bool(random.getrandbits(1)))  # checks if paper and dict_k matches

            if result == True:
                self.correct = self.correct + 1
            else:
                self.incorrect = self.incorrect + 1
            # self.qLbl.setText("{} {}".format(id_, result))
            self.qLbl.setText(" {} {} {}".format(str(ids_), self.correct, self.incorrect))
            self.color = QColor("green") if result==True else QColor("red")
            self.repaint()
            self.update()
        # return result

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.color.isValid():
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.color, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color, Qt.SolidPattern))
            painter.drawRect(40, 40, 400, 200)

qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
qWin = MainWindow()
qWin.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
qWin.show()
# run application
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

I would like to replicate similar process while getting ids live instead of getting it from list. The code below creates the UI however, it opens multiple window and displays data in multiple windows. It probably have to do with the for loop at the end, without for loop how can i update the graph?

Not working code is below :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor
import random
# from neo4j_validation import neo4jValidation
import time

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,id_, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # counter
        self.correct = 0
        self.incorrect = 0
        self.id_ = id_
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 8pt Arial}")
        self.qLbl = QLabel("Not yet initialized")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)
        self.qTimer = QTimer()
        self.qTimer.setInterval(1000)
        # self.qTimer.singleShot(1000, self.getSensorValue)
        self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.getSensorValue)
        self.qTimer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.qTimer.start()
        self.color = QColor()
        self.repaint()
        self.update()

    def getSensorValue(self):

        result = (bool(random.getrandbits(1)))
        if result == True:
            self.correct = self.correct + 1
        else:
            self.incorrect = self.incorrect + 1
        # self.qLbl.setText("{} {}".format(id_, result))
        self.qLbl.setText(" {} {} {}".format(str(self.id_), self.correct, self.incorrect))
        # self.color = QColor("green") if result==True else QColor("red")
        if result == True:
            self.color =QColor("green")
        elif result == False:
            self.color  = QColor("red")
        else:
            self.color =QColor("black")
        self.repaint()
        self.update()
            # return result

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.color.isValid():
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.color, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color, Qt.SolidPattern))
            painter.drawRect(40, 40, 400, 200)

#


qWin = []
ids=["id_123","id_234","id_345"]
qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
for i in range(len(ids)):
    qWin.append(MainWindow(ids[i]))
    time.sleep(1)
    qWin[i].setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
    qWin[i].show()

sys.exit(qApp.exec_())


# run application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where the ids are supposed to be coming from, but I believe subclassing QThread would suit your needs. This way the list of ids can be sent to the main class one at a time, without freezing the application loop the way `time.sleep()` does.

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class IDThread(QThread):

    ready = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ids = ["id_123", "id_234", "id_345"]

    def run(self):
        for x in self.ids:
            self.sleep(1)
            self.ready.emit(x)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # counter
        self.correct = 0
        self.incorrect = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 8pt Arial}")
        self.qLbl = QLabel("Not yet initialized")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)
        self.color = QColor()
        self.repaint()
        self.update()

        # create thread, connect signal, start thread
        self.id_thread = IDThread(self)
        self.id_thread.ready[str].connect(self.getSensorValue)
        self.id_thread.start()

    def getSensorValue(self, id_):
        result = (bool(random.getrandbits(1)))
        if result == True:
            self.correct = self.correct + 1
        else:
            self.incorrect = self.incorrect + 1
        # self.qLbl.setText("{} {}".format(id_, result))
        self.qLbl.setText(" {} {} {}".format(id_, self.correct, self.incorrect))
        # self.color = QColor("green") if result==True else QColor("red")
        if result == True:
            self.color =QColor("green")
        elif result == False:
            self.color  = QColor("red")
        else:
            self.color =QColor("black")
        self.repaint()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.color.isValid():
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.color, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color, Qt.SolidPattern))
            painter.drawRect(40, 40, 400, 200)


qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
qWin = MainWindow()
qWin.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
qWin.show()
# run application
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi alec, Thank you for your response. Would this not create the same issue I have with non-working code since I will have to define the list of ids before hand. Let's assume we get 1 id from each line in csv file. There could be 100 or million ids. I would like to generate this UI on the fly instead of reading csv and creating list of ids first. So as we go down the list of id in csv file, I want to generate this exact UI

Comment: I defined the id list because the ids had to come from somewhere, but this method is very flexible. So if you're getting the ids from a file, you can just add the file reading code to IDThread, and even emit ids to the main class as the file is read line by line.